# Concurrent calls to web service to COM application (Primavera ERP)

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services

I have a web service that calls a function and creates a sale in ERP PRIMAVERA, it does work if i call it sequentially, but if i call it concurrently, because ERP does not support Threads and can only create one at a time, the web service hangs both systems, client and ERP. I don't know how to solve this.
What can i do.?

i have tried to create a column in the log table that register the state of a call, but since the timing diference is in millisecond so the writing in the database gives me 2 calls with same state, therefore hangs the system.

```
    <WebMethod()>
    Public Function InsereVenda(ByVal id As String, ByVal xml As String) As String

        Dim ObjResp As New ObjResposta

        Try

            ObjResp = RetornaObjRespostaDocs("InsereVenda", id, xml)

            Return ObjResp.XMLResposta

        Catch ex As Exception
            If ex.Message = "" Then
                Return "Erro"
            Else

                Return ObjResp.XMLResposta
            End If


        End Try

    End Function
End Class


 Public Class Pedido
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    Private Function RetornaObjRespostaDocs(ByVal metodo As String, ByVal id As String, ByVal xml As String) As ObjResposta

        Dim msg As String = ""
        Dim servWeb As ServicosWeb
        Dim lista As DataTable

        RetornaObjRespostaDocs = New ObjResposta

        servWeb = New ServicosWeb(My.Settings.Username, My.Settings.Password, My.Settings.Empresa, My.Settings.TipoEmpresa)

        Try

            RetornaObjRespostaDocs.ID = id
            RetornaObjRespostaDocs.XML = xml
            RetornaObjRespostaDocs.DataProc = Now
            RetornaObjRespostaDocs.TipoMsg = metodo




            'While 1 < 2
            '    
            Thread.Sleep(1000)
            servWeb.GuardarRegistoTabelaLOGWebService(id, "", RetornaObjRespostaDocs.TipoMsg,
                                                          RetornaObjRespostaDocs.DataProc, RetornaObjRespostaDocs.XML, "", "0", "R")
            Thread.Sleep(1000)
            lista = servWeb.ConsultaSQLDatatable("select CDU_Estado from TDU_LogWebService  WITH (NOLOCK) where CDU_Estado = 'R'")

            If lista.Rows.Count <=0 Then
                servWeb.InsereVenda(xml, RetornaObjRespostaDocs)
                servWeb.GuardarRegistoTabelaLOGWebService(RetornaObjRespostaDocs.ID, RetornaObjRespostaDocs.Mensagem, RetornaObjRespostaDocs.TipoMsg,
            RetornaObjRespostaDocs.DataProc, RetornaObjRespostaDocs.XML, RetornaObjRespostaDocs.XMLResposta, RetornaObjRespostaDocs.Sucesso, "G")


            Else

                Thread.Sleep(1000)


            End If

            'End While




            Return RetornaObjRespostaDocs

        Catch ex As Exception

            servWeb.GuardarRegistoTabelaLOGWebService(RetornaObjRespostaDocs.ID, RetornaObjRespostaDocs.Mensagem, RetornaObjRespostaDocs.TipoMsg,
                        RetornaObjRespostaDocs.DataProc, RetornaObjRespostaDocs.XML, RetornaObjRespostaDocs.XMLResposta, RetornaObjRespostaDocs.Sucesso, "G")

            Return RetornaObjRespostaDocs

        End Try

    End Function

``
```

Comment: I don't think I can help you solve this, but I think it greatly increases the change others might if you translate your variable/function names to english and/or write comments in your code. Another option is to post on the [portugese StackOverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams that my code is ok, just the client app was calling it in the wrong way.